# For $\psi : R \to \prod^n_{i=1}R/I_i$, do we get $\ker(\psi)=\cap^n_{i=1}\ker(\pi_i)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring and $I_i$ be ideals. Let also $\pi_i: R \to R/I_i$ be the projection and  $\psi : R \to \prod^n_{i=1}R/I_i$ be a homomorphism. Is it always true, that $\ker(\psi)=\cap^n_{j=1}\ker(\pi_j)$?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: It seems to me to be logic. I mean if a take an element out of $\ker(\pi_j)$ than of course this would be $0$ in the jth component. If I take now one out of the intersection, each component will be zero and hence the kern, not?

Comment: Indeed. Now make this into an argument.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly $\ker(\pi_i)=I_i$. By definition of $\ker$:

$$ \ker(\psi)=\{x\in R\mid \pi_i(x)=0\  \forall\,i\} = \{x\in R\mid x\in I_i\  \forall\,i\} = \bigcap_{i=1}^n I_i $$